# How to make power query case insensitive for purpose of duplicate removal?

Tags: powerbi, powerquery

In power bi, I open the transform data, and import a table.

The table has name column with data like following:

```
Product 1
product 1
```

When I remove the duplicates, the power query is keeping both the above treating both as unique values being case sensitive.

How can I make power query case insensitive for purpose of duplicate removal?

Answer (score 6):

Since you posted no code, I am assuming you did this from the UI.  So:

- Go into the Advanced Editor
- Locate the line that starts with `Table.Distinct`
- Change the equation criteria to something like: `Table.Distinct(previousStep, {"ColumnName",Comparer.OrdinalIgnoreCase})`

  - Be sure to add this in the correct location.
  - Check MS Help for the command.

If you can't figure it out, post the relevant M-Code.

Comment: As of today, the MS Help has nothing on the equationCriteria. Instead, check out this page: https://blog.crossjoin.co.uk/2017/01/22/the-list-m-functions-and-the-equationcriteria-argument/